# Stuck on the third step of the V2 OAuth authentication flow

Tags: nestjs, slack, slack-api

I have created my first bot, and now I'd like to submit to the Slack App directory.
As the [tutorial](https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2) says, I should create an endpoint which for Slack to reach when the user approves my app. Slack should send me a temporary code, which in turn I should send back to their OAuth API. This is the relevant code (it's a NestJS app btw):

```
@Get()
auth(@Query('code') code: string) {
  const url = 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access';
  const message = {
    client_id: 'my.client.id',
    client_secret: 'my.client.secret',
    code: 'my.code'
  }
  return this.httpService.post(url, message);
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "error": "invalid_arguments",
  "response_metadata": {
    "messages": [
      "[ERROR] missing required field: code"
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrea,

When I look at the slack api definition for that method:

https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.v2.access

I noticed it says

```
Present arguments as parameters in application/x-www-form-urlencoded querystring or POST body. This method does not currently accept application/json.
```

Are you passing that header or url encoding the parameters?

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
```

The reason I ask is that if I visit something like this in a browser

```
https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access?client_id=00000&client_secret=11111&code=33333
```

I actually get

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_code"}
```

which is correct because I provided a code in the url parameters list - albeit an invalid code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was able to complete the OAuth flow by encoding the `message` with the `qs` library, in this way: `this.http.post(url, qs.stringify(grant))`